# Google maps api request from apex batch

Tags: google-map

everyone.

I am trying to run batch, wich will fill the geolocation field on accounts. And for now, i have an issue with http request, that fails.

so, here it is

```
public static String[] getCoordinates(String commonAddress){ 
  String[] Coordinates; 

  String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?';
  url += 'address=' + commonAddress; 
  url += '&sensor=false'; 

  system.debug(Logginglevel.ERROR,'GeoUtilitiesCoordinates url: ' + url);    

  Http h = new Http(); 
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

  req.setMethod('GET');
  req.setEndpoint(url); 

  String responseBody;
  if (!Test.isRunningTest()){ 
  // Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req); 
    system.debug('res // ' + res);
    responseBody = res.getBody();
  }
  else {
    // dummy data
    responseBody = '\"location\" : { \"lat\" : 32.0719776,\"lng\" : 34.7914048}';
  } 
  system.debug('responseBody // ' + responseBody);

  /*
     body parsing should be here
  */

  return Coordinates; 
}
```

The problem is - i have System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400] in my debug log.

but the request itself
System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Nottingham,&sensor=false, Method=GET]

has a correct endpoint and it works fine in browser.

Response body says

Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  That’s all we know.

What is the problem could be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience, the error Google is throwing back at you is because the URL wasn't formatted correctly. Most commonly, it's because there was a space in the address variable instead of the plus/+ sign. For example, in your URL let's say it would say:

`System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Nottingham,+UK&sensor=false, Method=GET]`

Instead of

`System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Nottingham, UK&sensor=false, Method=GET]`

I understand in your example that it doesn't show anything past "Nottingham," but I have a feeling this is what is causing your error. Try adding code to replace white space with plus signs and see if it resolves your problem.

Good luck!

**EDIT:** Keep in mind that using server side geocoding is limited to 5 requests per second, and 2,500 per day without paying for an API key. If you are going to be transcribing more than 5 more second, then you will need to stagger them in batches of 5, at least one second a part from each other.

Comment: Yes, thats a point! I used my address from SF formula field from JS and browser and it seems that url was preformatted to delete whitespaces automatically.  About the limits - thats quit a headache for me, but the global brobles is - client wants to render 2300 address markes on the map, and some another developer made it by calling geocoder to get lat\long by address from VF page 2300 times in a loop to draw the markers *_*

Comment: That's what I figured was happening. So it is working now?

Comment: Welcome! Have a great day.